# iOS WKWebView is not supporting windowScriptObject like previous WebView

Tags: javascript, ios, webview, wkwebview

Able to communicate with javascript with **javascriptmessagehandler** but I need to pass an object to Javascript code with **WKWebView** like can do before with WebView as mentioned below but **windowScriptObject** is not supports **WKWebView**

```
 id win = [webView windowScriptObject];
    [win setValue:littleBlackBook forKey:@"AddressBook"];
```

is there is way to achieve below with WKWebview..
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/ObjCFromJavaScript.html